# Android: How can I speed up the scrolling of GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, imageview

I have a GridView that displays images (7 columns of images that are 166dp x 249dp) that are all the same size (there are over 150 images), and I'm using the view recycling mechanism through the view holder pattern by way of an adapter. My views are all simply ImageViews. There isn't much going on that should be slowing the scrolling on this widget (there are 21 images on screen at a time), but the thing just scrolls so choppy. What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Is this in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: On the device. Motorolla Xoom, Android 3.1

Comment: Where are the ImageView content coming from? Decoding a jpeg or png into a Bitmap object can take enough time to slow it down. You might want to cache image Bitmaps in memory to avoid doing the decoding over and over.

Comment: Initially the images come from the web, but once I get the bitmap I'm saving it to a file, and caching it locally in the parser in a map of SoftReferences that hold onto the Bitmaps (to avoid memory issues). If the image isn't in the softreference, on a background thread I check the file system for it, if that fails I hit the web. I tried just creating a big grid of static images that I just load from a resource id, but that is just as slow.

Comment: I have a grid of ImageViews 2 in a row and it's also pretty choppy. I use the same Bitmap caching too. I don't see GC when scrolling, so it's not that, yet it's still choppy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spoke with some of the boys at Google during the last Google Developer Lab and they told me that GridView is not maintained very much, and that I should use ListView, laying out the rows myself in code to make a grid. This is what I did and it's now lightning fast.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother you :) I have the exact same problem as you, and since you wrote that ListView could be used instead, I tried to search for some code examples on the net. However, I can't find any, so I'm wondering if you could please show us how you solved the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately the company I work for owns the copyright on that code, so I can't share it with you. However, I can tell you what you need to do. Simply use a ListView in place of your GridView. Write an Adapter (extend BaseAdapter), and in the getView method programmatically add however many Views (these are your columns) you require for the particular row (position) you are creating. Make sure you implement the ViewHolder pattern or you'll have memory and performance issues.