# How do you support the optical track pad on Android if you have a custom view with subviews?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a custom ListAdapter that holds many sub-views per row. I essentially replicated GridView because GridView performance sucked, and [according to another post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878886/android-how-can-i-speed-up-the-scrolling-of-gridview), the Google devs suggested they had/will be deprecating that component.

My implementation works, but I am now getting reports that the "optical track pad" on a T-Mobile G2 highlights on a per-row, not a per grid-item basis.

How can I indicate to the OS that my ListAdapter rows actually have N sub-views that should be highlighted and are clickable by the optical track pad?

I'm not even clear on what part of the Android documentation to look for this stuff in, so pointers there would also be appreciated.

Thanks!